# What is the Starting address of the stack Memory?

Tags: c++, memory, stack

Hi i had one of the interview question they were asked what is the starting address of the stack memory.
Please i don't know the address can you please help how to find the starting address of the stack memory.

Thanks & Regards,
Gunasekaran J

Comment: It depends on the environment (processor, OS, etc.).

Comment: FYI: [Where the top of the stack is on x86](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/04/where-the-top-of-the-stack-is-on-x86/)

Comment: Each thread usually has its own stack. Also ASLR may cause this to change each run of your application: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) on windows the default stack size is 1MB

Comment: That's an incredibly bad interview question. Unless they meant adding a variable at the beginning of your main() and outputting it's value. But still, those concept should all be abstracted away. I would never quiz my candidates about that, when there's much more interesting stuff.

Comment: There's no answer to that question. C++ doesn't even require you to have a stack. And even though it practise it does exist there is no standard way to get it's starting address.

Comment: Maybe its a question for discussion. They don't want an exact answer but want to know about your knowledge of the stack. I think for this purpose it can be a reasonable question.

Comment: On my one computer (well, two computers, either my Apple IIe or my CBM 8032), the STARTING ADDRESS of the stack is `0x0100`, and the ENDING ADDRESS of the stack is `0x01FF`.

Comment: @Jeffrey It's a great interview question (see below). The fact that it's abstracted away _is_ the answer! :)

Comment: Yeah, I should have said that if they want an exact address, (or make it seems like it) then it's terrible. If it is worded in a way that leaves it open to discussion, I agree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no guarantees in C++ that there even *is* a stack. Even if, in practice, there's one, the place it is in memory varies by compiler implementation, platform, environment, etc...

There's OS features like address randomization that will even force the address to change from run to run. You can't try to determine it programmatically as the compiler is allowed to modify/optimize your code.

Basically, the way to answer this question is to explain what a stack is, that its size does vary, that the position is irrelevant. Then explain the purpose it serves and how it is typically implemented. You can go so far as talk about early/simple CPU and the registers that implement it.

Comment: I think this is exactly the answer they are looking for. As a manager who has interviewed candidates several times if I asked someone this question on an interview I would be happy with this answer. A secondary motive for a question like this would be to evaluate the communication between you and the person you are interviewing.